# Reversing a linked list using stl

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, stl

I am trying to implement reversing of linked list data structure using vectors and standard library.I am getting an error

> ‘::system’ has not been declared using ::system;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<int> v[100];
  vector<int> v1;
  int n,i,k,j,x;
    cin>>n;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>x;
    v1.push_back(x);
  }cout<<"Given linked list"<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"->"<<v1[i];
  }cout<<endl;
  cin>>k;
  j=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    int y=v1[i];
    v[j].push_back(y);
    if((i+1)%k==0){
     j++;
    }
    }
  cout<<"Reversed Linked list"<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<=j;i++){
    reverse(v[i].begin(),v[i].end());
    for(k=0;k<v[i].size();k++){
      cout<<"->"<<v[i][k];
  }

  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Then read about [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse). Then [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read and learn C++ properly.

Comment: Just remove `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: As for your error, *where* do you get the error? On which line? The code you show doesn't have any symbol `system` in it.

Comment: okay i will remove <bits/stdc++.h>,but as an alternative should i use <vector>, <iostream> ,<algorithm>?

Comment: `<vector>` and `<algorithm>` I think

Comment: But your code still has errors. In particular I really don't think you want `vector<int> v[100];` that's an array of 100 empty vectors. Probably you want one vector of size 100 which would be `vector<int> v(100);` or maybe just one empty vector which would be `vector<int> v;`

Comment: I see that as the comments are being made the code is being editted. This gets very confusing.

Comment: I edited the code,and added new headers <vector> , <algortihm>. it still shows same error.

Comment: @AyushMishra Well the crucial question is which line the error refers to. As you can see there is nothing called `system` in your posted code. So the error is hard to understand without more detail from you.

Comment: @john this is the line- **from main.cpp:4:/usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdlib:158:11:**

Comment: OK, well that is not an error in your code, it refers to the header files not your code. It's either a) an error in the way your compiler has been installed, or b) an error in the way you are using your compiler. Again more details needed, but this has nothing at all to do with the code you have written.

Comment: If you want to traverse a list in reverse order, why don't you then simply iterate from `rbegin` to `rend` rather than from `begin` to `end`? Or construct a new list or vector from the reverse iterators? Seems to me that you are massively overcomplicating this.

Comment: @jesper Juhl reversing of linked list from a particular key element